# Adjective with or without ending (declension)

Tags: english-to-german, standard-german

> Weich gekochte Eier esse ich gern.

*Eier* is plural so why is it *weich* and not *weiche*.

*Original question*:
Eier ist plural.
Weich gekochte Eier esse ich gern.
Warum haben wir "weich" geschreiben. wir habenEier is plural im satz. Wir sollen "weiche" schreiben.

Comment: Sorry for heavily editing your question and I appreciate you trying to write in German, that's a good exercise. On this site we like to keep the title, question and answer in the same language though. So if you want the answer to be in English, please write an English title and include an English question in your post :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to grammar, you can use both versions, but the meaning differs slightly.

> Weich gekochte Eier esse ich gern.

Here, "weich" is an adverb (so its ending is fixed), and thus describes something about the process of "kochen", in this case meaning that you boil the eggs in such a way that the result is "weich".

> Weiche gekochte Eier esse ich gern.

Here, "weiche" is an adjective and describes some property of the eggs, and as an adjective, its ending follows the plural form of "Eier". So, the sentence expresses that you like eggs that satisfy two conditions:

- they have been boiled ("gekocht"),
- and they are soft ("weich").

This does not express how the eggs became "weich" (by boiling or whatever process).

When describing eggs, you'll hardly ever encounter the adjective phrase, the phrase with adverb is typically used, and (as @infinitezero writes) it describes eggs where the white part is solid, but the yellow part still mostly liquid.

Answer (score 8):

The tricky part about German is that there's no distinction in writing between adverbs and adjectives, as for example in English. Although you can argue that there is in this case, because if it were an adjective, it would indeed be wrong, as you correctly noticed.
In the above sentence, *weich* is an adverb that describes *gekocht*, not an adjective that describes *Eier*.

*Weich gekocht* means, that the white part of the egg is solid, while the yolk is still liquid (soft-boiled).